# React Native Facebook Flipper Thread 9: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20...1)

Tags: react-native, certificate, flipper, fbflipper

i'm having some issues with Flipper, never had it before so not sure if it's with their update or what's happening. Would love some help on it!

This is the error that i'm getting:
[image: image of environment]

I'm in Xcode Version 12.4 Let me know what else i can send you, here is Flipper in my podfile.

[image: Here is my Podfile]

Comment: I am having the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I have commented out use_flipper! and it worked from my end.